# Convert plot into an array of 1s and 0s

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to convert a plot where I've plotted shapes and filled them, into an array where the shapes are 1s and the white spaces are 0s. I've included the code for the plot below. Can I somehow use numpy to do this?

PLOT CODE:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#define plot window size
plt.axis([0, 280, 0, 270])

#define start point (x,y)
x_start=20
y_start=250
plt.plot(x_start,y_start,'ro')
plt.text(x_start,y_start,'START')

#define end point (x,y)
x_end=265
y_end=20
plt.plot(x_end,y_end,'ro')
plt.text(x_end,y_end,'END')

#define, display, and connect vertices of polygon1
x1 = [175,270,200,130,175]
y1 = [150,200,220,180,150]
#plt.scatter(x1,y1) #plot vertices
plt.plot(x1,y1,'b') #connect vertices with lines
plt.fill(x1, y1, 'b') #fill blue

#define, display, and connect vertices of polygon2
x2 = [50,100,150,50]
y2 = [255,150,230,255]
#plt.scatter(x2,y2)
plt.plot(x2,y2,'b')
plt.fill(x2, y2, 'b')

#define, display, and connect vertices of polygon3
x3 = [5,50,50,5,5]
y3 = [210,210,25,25,210]
#plt.scatter(x3,y3,)
plt.plot(x3,y3,'b')
plt.fill(x3,y3, 'b')

#define, display, and connect vertices of polygon4
x4 = [60,140,190,160,80,60]
y4 = [110,155,80,10,45,110]
#plt.scatter(x4,y4)
plt.plot(x4,y4,'b')
plt.fill(x4, y4, 'b')

#define, display, and connect vertices of polygon5
x5 = [280,255,185,280]
y5 = [160,60,20,160]
#plt.scatter(x5,y5)
plt.plot(x5,y5,'b')
plt.fill(x5, y5, 'b')

#display
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are actually trying to do overall, but plotting what is essentially a vector diagram and then rasterising it onto a grid and converting it to an image and then hoping that the dpi works out and decoding an image is not an ideal approach.

May I suggest you use **scikit-image** [polygon()](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.draw.html#polygon) instead?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
from skimage.draw import polygon

# Set height and width
h, w = 10, 12

# Create blank canvas
img = np.zeros((h, w), dtype=np.uint8)

# Define polygon
r = np.array([1, 8, 1])
c = np.array([1, 1, 10])

# Draw it
rr, cc = polygon(r, c)
img[rr, cc] = 1
print(img)
```

**Sample Output**

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0]
 [0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```